# PDCurses newwin() not initializing window in debugger

Tags: c++, gdb, codeblocks, pdcurses

I'm creating a roguelike in PDCurses on Windows 10. The game initializes several windows - the play area, an inventory area, etc. When running the program normally, all of those windows work. But when using the GDB debugger on Code::Blocks, the "statarea" window pointer will not initialize. This means that when debugging, the player's stats window is invisible. Any idea why this could be?

MAX_ROW and MAX_COL are constants for the size of the playarea. MAX_ROW = 22 and MAX_COL = 80. The values of the WINDOW pointers are checked at a breakpoint right after the initialization of said windows.

```
WINDOW * playarea = newwin(MAX_ROW, MAX_COL, 2, 2); //correctly initializes to some memory address
WINDOW * envtextarea = newwin(2,MAX_COL,0,1); //initializes correctly
WINDOW * statarea = newwin(3,MAX_COL,MAX_ROW+2,2); //"initializes" to 0x0 when using GDB, initializes correctly otherwise
WINDOW * invenarea = newwin(MAX_ROW,20,2,MAX_COL+4); //initializes correctly
```

Comment: Does the value of LINES differ when running under the debugger?

Comment: @WilliamMcBrine Just checked, LINES is smaller when using the debugger. So I guess that means the window isn't being initialized properly because there isn't enough space?

Comment: Yeah, PDCurses won't create a window with dimensions beyond the screen.